# Calculate the SUM for different year in SAS

Tags: sum, sas

I have one dummy variable, `emu3`, where I have 1.560 observations if `emu3=0` and 1.905 observations if `emu3=1`.

The data is for the period 1992-2006. I want to calculate the sum of the variable `avgflow` in each year when `emu3=0` and `emu3=1`.

I have tried with this one:

```
PROC MEANS DATA=EMUdummy2 NWAY ;
 CLASS emu3 ;
 VAR avgflow ;
 OUTPUT OUT=fam1 SUM=sumt;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=fam1;
 VAR sumt;
RUN;
```

But I am not sure if this is correct and I do not know how I do it for different year.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show a few records of your data?  It could be you just need to add YEAR to your CLASS statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a variable year, add it to the class statement in `PROC MEANS`.

```
PROC MEANS DATA=EMUdummy2 NWAY ;
 CLASS emu3 year;
 VAR avgflow ;
 OUTPUT OUT=fam1 SUM=sumt;
RUN;
```

Also, add emu3 and year to your `PROC PRINT`

```
PROC PRINT DATA=fam1;
 VAR emu3 year sumt;
RUN;
```

If you have a date variable (I'll assume it is called DATE) but no year variable, then you can create a YEAR variable like this:

```
data emudummy2;
  set emudummy2;
  year = year(date);
run;
```

Comment: creating new date variable would not be needed. You can simply use the date variable in PROC MEANS class statement and format the date variable as YEAR4. That should save the programmer from coding extra step or creating extra variable.